How to use RemoteApp without Windows Server or Domain?
I would like to host RemoteApps on a local computer with Windows 10 Pro and connect to these  apps from another installation.
This way I hope to be able to run a single app from my machine remotely without needing the full desktop experience active. I don't want a window with a desktop in it and a window on that desktop, I want the app to be between my local apps. It's frustrating to work on a desktop on my desktop. On top of that this is a super fascinating feature of which I want to make the most.
I know this is possible with the remote desktop protocol, Windows Server has a RemoteApp feature that allows multiple remote apps to float between local apps on your computer, where the remote apps are actually RDP connections but they look and feel like applications running on the local machine (apart from the image compression occasionally, althought the compression is less noticable on a single app than the entire desktop).
Another place I have seen this is Windows XP Mode for Windows 7. With Windows XP Mode you can install applications and most third party apps that are added to the start menu in Windows XP Mode also get added to a folder on the Start menu of the host machine, where you can then put Windows Virtual PC to sleep and connect to it again in this RemoteApp mode. This allows Windows XP apps to run on top of Windows 7 (or whatever your host is) while having the Windows XP borders and behaviour as if it's actually running on the Host but it's individual apps running via RDP.
It was also possible to do some registry tweaks to enable shortcuts to run any app in Windows XP Mode as a RemoteApp allowing for things like this:

Going from Windows Virtual PC to Hyper-V this feature doesn't exist in Hyper-V despite Hyper-V also using RDP just like Windows Virtual PC. I know it has to be possible in Hyper-V too, so if I know how to do it between two local machines, it can be done on Hyper-V too to make Hyper-V functionally just as capable as Windows Virtual PC. This RemoteApp thing in Virtual PC only works with Windows XP integration features. (Maybe Windows 98 or 95 have integration features too but I only tried it myself on XP Mode.)
Seeing that functionality like the "RemoteApp" feature existed at least already since Vista, I know it is possible to use it and I know it works without Windows Server because it's done in Windows Virtual PC completely locally hosted. It even exists on Microsoft Remote Desktop 8 and 10 for Mac OS X 10.6.6 and up:

There is also this article where you can see the remote apps are launched by mstsc.exe which I assume stands for Microsoft Terminal Services Client.
I assume only the host machine needs to do something special and the client just needs to connect with the correct parameters.
How do I enable this functionality to connect to a single app hosted on a regular Windows Pro installation?
If there is no way to do this configuration or pull off some tricks to make Windows do this for me with first party software, is there any third party software available that can do this, or can I write my own software that pulls this off?

Does this answer your question? remote desktop - How can I enable RemoteApp serving in Windows 10?

@Cpt.Whale The question itself would answer my question. I would only find this question if I knew the answer to my question first, since this is a question about the tool provided in response to my question and not my question itself. It took me some research to even know the name of this feature was RemoteApp.

RemoteApp Tool says it's able to define the necessary registry keys.

Oh my god! I fell off my chair when I tried it and it actually works!!! I almost can't believe  this actually exists and I wasn't able to find this myself after months of wondering how I can get this to work. The experience is even faster and better than I imagined, this feels 10 times faster than a full desktop connection. Even more incredible, even UWP apps work. This is EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you so so much!
